# Magento2: Translate META TAGS (Meta description) in layout XML files

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend, xml

We have created a custom page that is shown on some specific situations.

We successfully modified the META tags inside  section in various layout files.

The question is: How can we make this text translatable.
[image]

tag can be translated. But  and  no?!

I also found this link. It is one year old and its maybe a Magento BUG.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35191

Does some have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thank you